# replace a bunch of show/hide with switch/case in javascript

Tags: javascript, show-hide, switch-statement

Page has menu items that would replace a 'div id=foo_(current menu item)' with 'div id=foo_(selected menu item)' in 'div class=foo'

Here's what I've got, and try to keep your breakfast down...

```
    $('#t1').click(function() {
        $('#attorney').show();
        $('#insurance,#financial,#estate,#trust,#death').hide();
    });

    $('#t2').click(function() {
        $('#insurance').show();
        $('#attorney,#financial,#estate,#trust,#death').hide();
    });

    $('#t3').click(function() {
        $('#financial').show();
        $('#attorney,#insurance,#estate,#trust,#death').hide();
    });

    $('#t4').click(function() {
        $('#estate').show();
        $('#attorney,#insurance,#financial,#trust,#death').hide();
    });

    $('#t5').click(function() {
        $('#trust').show();
        $('#attorney,#insurance,#financial,#estate,#death').hide();
    });

    $('#t6').click(function() {
        $('#death').show();
        $('#attorney,#insurance,#financial,#estate,#trust').hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch statements are kind-of ugly.

```
var things = ['attorney', 'estate', 'insurance', 'financial', 'trust', 'death'];
var guide = {
  t1: 'attorney', t2: 'estate', t3: 'insurance', t4: 'financial', t5: 'trust', t6: 'death'
};

$('#t1, #t2, #t3, #t4, #t5, #t6').click(function() {
  var clicked = $(this).attr('id');
  $.each(things, function(_, thing) {
    var $thing = $('#' + thing);
    if (guide[clicked] == thing) $thing.show(); else $thing.hide();
  });
});
```

You might also consider setting up the event handler with `live()` instead of directly on the "t" thingies, whatever they are. It would also be neater if all the "things" (attorney, etc) could be given a class name, because then you could just hide them all quickly in the click handler with

```
   $('.thingClass').hide();
```

and then just make the one visible that's appropriate for the tab that was clicked. Then it could look something like this:

```
var guide = {
  t1: 'attorney', t2: 'estate', t3: 'insurance', t4: 'financial', t5: 'trust', t6: 'death'
};
$('#t1, #t2, #t3, #t4, #t5, #t6').click(function() {
  $('.thingClass').hide();
  $('#' + guide[$(this).attr('id')]).show();
});
```

Finally, you might consider letting one of the available jQuery tab plugins handle this whole thing for you :-)

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks.

As for $('.thingClass').hide - would that be on a $(window).load(function() { ?

As for the jQuery... I've had some issues with cross-contamination with other jQuery plugins on the page. There are several plugins on the page already. Javascript seems to be the least invasive solution.

Again, thanks a lot.

Comment: No what I meant was that in the click handler, you'd just hide *everything*, and then call .show() for the one that's appropriate.  It'd replace that "each" loop; I'll edit the answer to be more clear.